# Angular, Check Undefined in path variable - Lambda function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lambda, monads

how can I set null 'typeImageToLoad' variable if ($scope.pageToModify.image.type, $scope.pageToModify.image or $scope.pageToModify) can be null or Undefined?

Is it better using Lambda function?

This example doesn't work.

```
    if($scope.pageToModify.image.type){
          $scope.typeImageToLoad = $scope.pageToModify.image.type;
    }else {
          $scope.typeImageToLoad = null;
    }
    $scope.loadImage($scope.typeImageToLoad);
```

Some advice?

Comment: Honestly I did not understand your question, can you be more clear?

Comment: You have a contradiction in your question. You mention `$scope.pageToModify.image.type` and `$scope.type`. Which of the two is it? Is `type` a property of `$scope` or of `$scope.pageToModify.image`?

Answer (score 1):

The condition needs to check for the presence of each property separately:

```
if($scope.pageToModify && $scope.pageToModify.image && $scope.pageToModify.image.type){
```

Note that you can replace the `if...else` code with this:

```
$scope.typeImageToLoad = 
    $scope.pageToModify && $scope.pageToModify.image && $scope.pageToModify.image.type 
    || null;
```